# Why is my pivot chart not saving properly in Access 2010?

Tags: windows-7, charts, microsoft-access-2010

Working in Access 2010 and am trying to build a pivot chart from a query.  My query is looking at an item type (multiple possible) and closure date with the intention of creating a stacked bar chart.  The problem is that I can create the chart properly using the pivot drop zones in design mode but when I save and re-open, the value I placed in the data area has 'disappeared' from the chart.  Any ideas?

[image: Design Mode]

[image: After closing and re-opening]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, very irritating. By trial and error I found I could save the chart with another name, different from the underlying query. That seems to work, it first opens up as a table of the underlying query and then I right click the 'tab' (my access windows are tabbed) and select the pivot chart icon. Hey presto !

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you can also view in SQL & overwrite the semicolon & then save it will save with your updated pivot chart settings